# Creating a View of nodes with field for workbench moderation state without showing every revision?

Tags: views, nodes, workbench

I am trying to create a table view of nodes with fields for node title and moderation state. (There are other fields but I'm omitting them for simplicity).

Currently, it's displaying a new table row for every single revision of the node. I only want to see one row per node, whatever the current state is. Grouping is not sufficient, since there are fields that are not the same across revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after asking this question, I realized there is a filter criterion that can be added for this.

`Workbench Moderation: Current` can be set to filter based on whether a revision is the current one, and all previous ones can be excluded.

This will also exclude nodes that haven't been created or edited since the enabling of Workbench Moderation for their node type but will include newly created or edited ones.